# Bypass Certificate Error Using Http

Tags: https, dart

I'm trying to create a proxy server that access third-party API, but their development end point have certificate error. Is there anyway to bypass ssl error when using http.dart?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Uri url = Uri.parse("https://url-with-ssl-error.com/endpoint");
http.get(url).then((response) => print(response.body));
```

and here's the error returned:

```
Uncaught Error: SocketIOException: RawSecureSocket error (Unexpected handshake error in client) (OS Error: errno = -8172)
Unhandled exception:
SocketIOException: RawSecureSocket error (Unexpected handshake error in client) (OS Error:  errno = -8172)
#0      _FutureImpl._scheduleUnhandledError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:207:9)
#1      Timer.run.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/timer.dart:17:21)
#2      Timer.run.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/timer.dart:25:13)
#3      Timer.Timer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch:15:15)
#4      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:6990:28)
#5      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:6998:7)
#6      _Timer._createTimerHandler.<anonymous closure> (dart:io:7006:23)
#7      _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch:81:92)
```

Comment: can you show the relevant part of the code and the exact error?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic I've edit my questions with the code and the error returned

Comment: try adding `SecureSocket.initialize()` before `get`. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964492/socketioexception-unexpected-handshake-error-in-client and http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7541

Comment: what is the type of `http`?

Answer (score 5):

Though this question may be out of date, I should still post a short answer for this, in case of someone in the same trouble. This snippet's from my project:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart';
...

HttpClient client = new HttpClient()..badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
var ioClient = new IOClient(client);
http.Response resp = await ioClient.post(uri, body: utf8.encode(json.encode(body)), headers: headers);
...
```

The issue was mentioned [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/14) and also the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Error -8172 means that 'Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.'

If you had access to the raw socket, then [`connect`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/SecureSocket.html#connect) method allows you to specify what to do in case of bad certificate by providing `onBadCertificate` callback. However, I am not sure what is the exact type of `http` object in your code sample, so i can't tell whether you can workaround this or not. I thought it might be an `HttpClient` instance but it doesn't have a `get` method which takes a URI, so I am not sure. If it is your own class, maybe you have access to underlying secure socket so you can still use `onBadCertificate`.

Additionally, for server sockets, you can't rely on implicit [`SecureSocket.initialize()`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/SecureSocket.html#initialize) call. You need to [call it explicitly with certificate db info](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7541#c7).

Comment: I took a quick look at the http package, but I haven't seen the way to control bad certificate.

Comment: You can request a feature for the http package at http://dartbug.com/new. Thanks!