# How to use a SecureSocket to fix a HandshakeException?

Tags: dart, client-certificates

I am trying to connect to my school's intranet. Connecting with anything else than Dart is possible (in Python, PHP, with `curl -s -L "https://intra.42.fr/?format=json"`, and so on).

But the Dart VM considers that the TLS certificate in use in my school is bad. With this code:

```yaml
# pubspec.yaml
name: handshake-fail
dependencies:
  http: any
```

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main() { 
  var client = new http.Client();
  client.post('https://intra.42.fr/?format=json', body: {"login": "test", "password": "test"})
    .then((response) => print(response.body)
    );
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Uncaught Error: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized., errno = -8179)
Unhandled exception:
HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized., errno = -8179)
#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:700)
#1      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:23)
#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:32)
#3      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:36)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:119)
```

---

The question *[Bypass Certificate Error Using Http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524659/bypass-certificate-error-using-http)* points to a bug report [that suggests](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7541#c3):

> Optional parameters to [[`SecureSocket`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart:io.SecureSocket)]`.initialize` let you specify a certificate database (a directory containing `cert9.db` and `key4.db`), and whether or not to use the builtin well-known authorities.

My question is, **how to do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```dart
var cl = new HttpClient();
cl.badCertificateCallback = () => print(x);
```

dartdoc of `badCertificateCallback`

```
* Sets a callback that will decide whether to accept a secure connection
* with a server certificate that cannot be authenticated by any of our
* trusted root certificates.
```

Comment: It seems to work with `(X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;` as a callback. Unfortunately this solution only works for `HttpClient`, not for `http`.